# Change button background image when div is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, button

I have this bit of code to fade out and change the div on click of the relevant link. I would like images as my links instead of just "dealer, advertise etc." As well as that though I would the image to change to another image when the corresponding div is active.

So for example. When the "dealeroff.jpg" image is clicked it will change to "dealeron.jpg" until another image is clicked and the active div is changed.

```
<ul id="controlls">  
  <li><a href="#" id="one" class="dealer">Dealer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="two" class="advertise">Advertise</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="three" class="social">Social Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="four" class="need">Need</a></li>
</ul>

 <div id="slider">
    <div id="dealer">
        <p>If you click on this paragraph
          you'll see it just fade away.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="advertise">
        <p>If you click on this paragraph
        you'll see it just fade away.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
        <p>If you click on this paragraph
        you'll see it just fade away.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="need">
        <p>If you click on this paragraph
        you'll see it just fade away.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#controlls li a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).attr('class'); // get class of clicked anchor tag
      // first fadeOut the visible div
$('#slider div:visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
    // after fadeOut complete show target div
    $('div#' + id).fadeIn();
  })
});
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: have you looked into using a class combined with css to affect the background image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this :

```
<ul id="controlls">  
    <li><img src="dealeroff.jpg"    id="one"   class="dealer" /></li>
    <li><img src="advertiseoff.jpg" id="two"   class="advertise" /></li>
    <li><img src="socialoff.jpg"    id="three" class="social" /></li>
    <li><img src="needoff.jpg"      id="four"  class="need" /></li>
</ul>
```

with the JS

```
$("#controlls li img").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var div = $('#' + this.className);

   $("#controlls li img").not(this).attr('src', function(_,source) {
       return source.replace('on', 'off');
   });

   $(this).attr('src', function(_,source) {
       if ( source.indexOf('off') != -1 ) {
           return source.replace('off', 'on');
       } else {
           return source.replace('on', 'off');
       }
   });

   $('#slider div:visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
       div.fadeIn();
   });

});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks :) All working. How would I edit the JS so the first button is in the "on" image and displaying the "dealer" div on page load? As at the moment on page load the all the div's are displayed until a button is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/Tjh3G/ Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a class e.g. `.active` depending on whether a link is active or not and define two different backgrounds depending on the class being set or not. See this JSfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/B398u

HTML

```
<ul id="controlls">  
  <li><a href="#" data-target="#dealer" id="one">Dealer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="#social" id="two">Social Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="#need" id="three">Need</a></li>
</ul>

 <div id="slider">
    <div id="dealer">
        <p>Dealer paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
        <p>Social paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div id="need">
        <p>Need paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a#one {
    /* replace `red` with `url('imageoff.png');` */
    background: red;
}
a#one.active {
    /* replace `blue` with `url('imageon.png');` */
    background: blue;
}
a#two {
    background: red;
}
a#two.active {
    background: blue;
}
a#three {
    background: red;
}
a#three.active {
    background: blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#controlls li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);

    var id = $this.data('target');

    $('#controlls li a').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    $('#slider div').hide().filter(id).show();
});
});
```

Comment: This would work for me but I'm using different images for each button/link :)

Comment: Could I have a different "off and on" image for each individual link though? Would this be easy to implement? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is no problem to do this using CSS. See my modified answer.